# Oracle ora-00907 missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

What's wrong with the code?

I got error ora-00907 missing right parenthesis

```
SELECT
      (SELECT AMOUNT FROM LATERAL (SELECT cro.AMOUNT
      FROM some_schema.cred cro
      WHERE cro.cr_id = co.cr_id) WHERE ROWNUM = 1)

FROM some_schema.cred_oper co
```

ORACLE version 11.2.0.4.0

Comment: Remove the `LATERAL` - it's not needed to begin with (and maybe not even supported by the Oracle version you are using - which you didn't tell us)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LATERAL is only available in 12c and later versions of Oracle. I'm not sure what you're attempting to do here, but it appears your query can be simplified to:

```
SELECT cro.AMOUNT
  FROM some_schema.cred cro
  INNER JOIN some_schema.cred_oper co
    ON cro.cr_id = co.cr_id
  WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Best of luck.

Comment: I don't need simplify it, it's just a little simplified piece of code

Answer (score 0):

i think your query will be like below

```
SELECT        
  (
  SELECT sum(cro.AMOUNT)
  FROM some_schema.cred cro
  WHERE cro.cr_id = co.cr_id
 ) as amount
FROM some_schema.cred_oper co
```

Comment: anyway, subquery return more than 1 row

Comment: @ShakirovRamil  you need aggregation here so im going to sum(amount) is that ok, as you have not shared sample data so i could not get what amount you need, i tried to correct the query